# How to remove(delete) multiple users from different tables using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-delete

I wrote this query to delete one user from different tables using pl/sql.

Example: I run this query to delete one user:

**user** `SPIKETJ`, **code** `01234`, **code_id** `85412974` and **l_code_user** `SPIKETJ`

```
declare 
  l_code_name  table_2.cod_name%type;
  l_code       table_2.cod_emp%type;
  l_code_id    table_0.cod_id%type;
  l_code_user  table_03.cod_user%type;    
begin
  l_code_name := 'SPIKETJ';
  l_code := '01234';
  l_code_id := '85412974';
  l_code_user := 'SPIKETJ';

  DELETE table_2 WHERE cod_emp  IN (l_code);
  commit;

  DELETE table_65 WHERE cod_emp IN (l_code);
  commit;

  DELETE table_41 WHERE cod_name IN (l_code_name);
  commit;

  DELETE table_18 WHERE cod_name IN (l_code_name);
  commit;

  DELETE table08 WHERE cod_user IN (l_code_name);
  commit;

  DELETE table_0 WHERE cod_docum IN (l_code_id);
  commit;

  DELETE table_17 WHERE cod_id IN (l_code_id);
  commit;

  DELETE table_03 WHERE cod_user IN (l_code_user);
  commit;

END;
```

When I have to delete one user I only change/assign values for:
    `l_code_name`, `l_code`, `l_code_id`, `l_code_user`.

But now, I have to delete almost 20 users!
So I wanna know if I have to run this query 20 times changing the variable values each time ?

**OR**

Can I write a query/block where running one time deletes the 20 users I wish to?

Comment: Ugh. The dreaded l_ prefix for "local variables".

Comment: Create a procedure that takes the user code etc. as parameters, then call it 20 times.

Comment: do you have an example? @TonyAndrews

Comment: @spikeTJ example added below .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Create procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm) as suggested above by Tony Andrews.

**Procedure**

```
Create or replace Procedure Delete_user
(l_code_name IN your_users.cod_name%type,    --   Declare your IN parameters here
l_code       IN your_users.cod_emp%type,
l_code_id    IN your_users.cod_id%type,
l_code_user  IN your_users.cod_user%type
)
AS
--   Declare your local variables
v_code_name your_users.cod_name%type := l_code_name;    
v_code      your_users.cod_emp%type  := l_code;
v_code_id   your_users.cod_id%type   := l_code_id ;
v_code_user your_users.cod_user%type := l_code_user;
BEGIN
--- write your code(delete statements)
DELETE from your_users
WHERE cod_emp  IN (v_code);
commit;
dbms_output.put_line( 'USER : ' || ' ' ||  v_code_user || ' is deleted.' );
---
--- similarly other delete statements
END DELETE_USER;
```

**Output:**

```
Procedure created.
```

**check for errors using below command :**

Show errors;

no errors

**Call your Procedure for deleting users :**

```
 BEGIN
 DELETE_USER('SPIKETJ',01234,85412974,'SPIKETJ');
 DELETE_USER('JACKET',99999,111111,'JACKET');
 --similary add other user details in order of the parameters declared in proc
 END;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
USER :  SPIKETJ is deleted.
USER :  JACKET is deleted.

Statement processed.
```

Read more here [Procedures](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php)

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, but how could i make an one .sql file where i defined the all users to delete? I need to run one times. Do you recommend to me a procedure, but what do you think a for loop? @mahendar-mahi

Comment: Yes you can do it one `.SQL` file. write procedure first. Then call your procedure. I won't suggest `LOOP`

Comment: ok but i have to call the procedure 20 times or more. How I can set the value of the variables that go taking on their own? not to invoke the procedure 20 times. @mahendar-mahi

Comment: possible if you have all users listed in a master table with status as say `ACTIVE` and `INACTIVE` (these need to be deleted) using a `cursor`

Comment: What is the primary key in `table2` ?

Comment: @spikeTJ check out the new answer

Answer (score 1):

For deleting users instead of calling procedure `N` (20) times.

```
Create or replace Procedure Delete_user
 AS 
v_code_id   your_users.cod_id%type;  
v_code_user your_users.cod_user%type ;
cursor C_users is select cod_id,cod_user from your_users
 where 1=1;  -- add condition to select users you wish to delete   

BEGIN
OPEN C_users;
loop
Fetch C_users into v_code_id,v_code_user;
exit when C_users%NOTFOUND;
DELETE from your_users WHERE cod_emp  IN (v_code_id); -- use your primary key 
--- write delete statements for other tables
dbms_output.put_line( 'USER : ' || ' ' ||  v_code_user || ' is deleted.' );
End Loop;
commit;
Close C_users ;

END DELETE_USER;

 -- Procedure created.
```

**Output:**

```
USER :  mahi is deleted.
USER :  xyz is deleted.

Statement processed.
```

Comment: The both solutions works fine. After analyzing I preferred the first solution that you raised. @mahendar-mahi

Comment: Glad that I was of help